# Wordpresss: help display advanced custom field image inside wordpress custom posts ui loop

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

[image][image]

```html
<div class="row">

    <?php $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'website_feature', 'orderby'=> 'post_id', 'order' => 'ASC')); ?>

    <?php while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();?>

      <div class="col-sm-3">
                <img src="<?php the_field('website_feature_icon'); ?>" alt="" > --- This is the image I am trying to display

    <img src="<?php echo $website_feature_icon['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $website_feature_icon['alt']; ?>"> -- I am trying again here

  <?php if($url!='') { --- This makes the featured image appear
       echo '<a href="'.$url.'">';
       echo the_post_thumbnail('full');
       echo '</a>';
     } else {
       echo the_post_thumbnail('full');
     } ?>

        <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
      </div><!-- end col -->

    <?php endwhile; ?>

  </div><!-- row -->
```

The website feature is a custom post type ui. The title shows perfectly for each post. The image is an advanced custom field and I can not get it to display for each post, the best I can get it working is to display a string of the array lol. I have managed to make it working using the featured image from normal WP functionality but I would love to get this working using the advanced custom field image so its more user friendly, as the rest of the site does not use featured image anywhere.

Comment: @cale_b I have edited the post/code to show which images aren't working and the featured image that does. I have also made it more clearer that I am using advanced custom fields.

Comment: @cale_b Dam I was excited to troubleshoot then but I get a 500 error when using:   <?php  var_dump( get_the_field('website_feature_icon'); ?> or   <?php  var_dump( get_the_field('website_feature_icon') ?> or var_dump( get_the_field('website_feature_icon'); :/

Comment: @cale_b Ok fixed that, so I get this for each of the posts images: 59, , services-payperclick-optimized, , , image/png, http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/services-payperclick-optimized.png, 260, 260, ArrayNULL - Can't see how this is going to help me too much :/

Comment: Please edit your question, and copy-paste _the exact output_ from ONE of your `var_dump`.  It is in fact super helpful, but without formatting, it's hard to utilize.

Comment: 59, , services-payperclick-optimized, , , image/png, http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/services-payperclick-optimized.png, 260, 260, ArrayNULL - Thats it from one var_dump... I am not sure how to get it any cleaner then that or with formatting.

Comment: OK, you've been helpful so far, but you're not doing what I ask now - and remember, I'm just trying to help.  Please - edit your question, put the `var dump` results inside a code block to get it formatted. `var_dump` is super valuable and useful, but what you're putting into the comments is super difficult to parse / understand because of the lack of formatting.

Comment: Note: view [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php#example-6199) to see what a `var_dump` should look like, formatted...

Comment: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/code-examples/#working-with%20images%20%E2%80%93%20id